# Passing Application as parameter

Tags: android, repository, android-room, android-context

I'm using Room to implement database, code for working with database is located into Repository, to get instance of database Repository needs Application as class atribute, I want to get instance of Repository in class that extends IntentService and in class that extends Worker class, now, they don't need Application as atribute but to be able to use Repostiory into them I must add it, is this good programming practice? Maybe some other soluction?

```
public class SunshineSyncIntentService extends IntentService {

    private Application mApplication;

    public SunshineSyncIntentService(@NotNull Application application) {
        super("SunshineSyncIntentService");
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SunshineSyncTask.syncWeather(mApplication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, is not a bad practice. But I rather use some dependency injection as a more robust solution. You can take a look on Dagger or Koin (for Kotlin).